# Determine who called delegate method

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

In my project I have some scroll views and a tableviews. I have implemented delegate method `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` It is called by scroll view and also by tableview,(Since tableview is a subclass of scroll view). I want to know the method is not called by table view. How can I do so?

Comment: UIScrollView is a parent class of UITableView, You can check this using isKindOfClass.. as Alexander is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple check like this one should do the trick:

```
if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] == YES) {
    // table
}
else {
    // scroll view
}
```

Or set & compare tags for multiple tables/scroll views